Laravel's request data casted into string (should be integer)
I have this validation rules in request class:
public function rules(): array
{
    $countries = getCountriesForValidation();

    return [
        'total_capital_cost' => 'required|integer|in:' . implode(',', CapitalCosts::getCases()),
        'investment_amount_id' => 'required|integer|in:' . implode(',', InvestmentAmounts::getCases()),

        'other_income' => 'array',
        'other_income.other_income_sources' => 'required_with:other_income|integer|in:' . implode(',', IncomeSources::getCases()),
        'other_income.income_frequency' => 'required_with:other_income|integer|in:' . implode(',', IncomeFrequencies::getCases()),

        'overseas_transfers_last_year' => 'array',
        'overseas_transfers_last_year.funds_transfer_country' => 'required_with:overseas_transfers_last_year|integer|in:' . $countries,

        'incoming_funds_last_year' => 'array',
        'incoming_funds_last_year.funds_origin_country' => 'required_with:incoming_funds_last_year|integer|in:' . $countries
    ];
}

As you can see, several fields are required to be integer. However, when I call $request->validated() in the controller, it returns all validated values as strings, even though they were specified as integers.
I’m converting the validated data to JSON to store it in the database. I also have another API that returns this submitted data.
The issue is that even if I send integer values, I receive them as strings in the response due to Laravel's request handling. This makes it difficult for the front-end to handle the response consistently, as the data types can vary between integer and string.

what exactly is the issue? what have you tried so far? having an integer validation has nothing to do with data type conversion, as the validation is not strict it checks if the content is an integer rather than if the type matches.

To solve the issue you need to implement type casting the value either  during validation (with prepareForValidation) or after validation (with model casts).

Pay attention to App\Http\Kernel in the $middleware property there are options that change the requester, maybe (string to null, trim pass, etc). Maybe you have your own more

Found global solution for this issue
I have overridden the validated() method of the FormRequest class to cast fields specified by integer rules to integers.
public function validated($key = null, $default = null)
{
    // Call the parent validated method to get the initial validated data
    $validatedData = parent::validated($key, $default);

    // Get the validation rules
    $rules = $this->rules();

    // Loop through each rule
    foreach ($rules as $field => $rule)
    {
        // Split the field into parts for nested arrays
        $fieldParts = explode('.', $field);

        // Start with the root of the validated data
        $currentData = &$validatedData;

        // Traverse the nested structure based on the field parts
        foreach ($fieldParts as $part)
        {
            // Check if currentData is an array and contains the part
            if (is_array($currentData) && array_key_exists($part, $currentData))
            {
                // Move deeper into the nested array
                $currentData = &$currentData[$part];
            }
            else
            {
                // If part is not found, skip to the next field
                continue 2;
            }
        }

        // If the data at the current field is null, skip integer conversion
        if ($currentData === null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        // If the rule requires integer conversion, cast the data to integer
        if ($this->hasIntegerRule($rule))
        {
            $currentData = (int) $currentData;
        }
    }

    // Return the modified validated data
    return $validatedData;
}

private function hasIntegerRule($rule): bool
{
    // Check if the rule is an array and contains 'integer'
    if (is_array($rule))
    {
        return in_array('integer', $rule);
    }

    // Check if the rule string contains 'integer'
    return str_contains($rule, 'integer');
}

